# SimpleSchema invalid keys with nested autoValue

Tags: meteor, schema

I have a schema like so (fluff cut out):

```
Schemas.people = new SimpleSchema({
  note: {
    type: [Schemas.notes],
    optional: true,
    defaultValue: []
  },
  updates: {
    type: [Schemas.updates],
    optional:true,
    autoValue:function(){
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return [{
          at: new Date,
          user_id: this.userId
        }];
      } 
      return {
        $push:{
          at: new Date,
          user_id: this.userId
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And the notes schema looks like:

```
Schemas.notes = new SimpleSchema({
  note: {
    type: String,
    autoform: {
      afFieldInput:{
        type:"textarea"
      }
    },
    optional: true
  },
  updates: {
    type: [Schemas.updates],
    optional:true,
    autoform:{
      omit:true
    },
    autoValue:function(){
      if (this.isInsert) {
        return [{
          at: new Date,
          user_id: this.userId
        }];
      } 
      return {
        $push:{
          at: new Date,
          user_id: this.userId
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

And the updates schema is super simple:

```
Schemas.updates = new SimpleSchema({
  at: {
    type: Date
  },
  user_id:{
    type: Meteor.ObjectID
  }
});
```

The "updates" field on the `people` schema saves the date/user id as expected when an update is made. However, it fails on the `notes` schema:

```
SimpleSchema invalid keys for "blablabla" context:
0: Object
  name: "note.0.updates.0.at"
  type: "keyNotInSchema"
  value: Mon May 11 2015 11:57:58 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
1: Object
  name: "note.0.updates.0.user_id"
  type: "keyNotInSchema"
  value: "abcd1234"
```

I believe that the "name" should look like "people.note.0.updates.0.at" but I'm unsure that this assumption is correct and I'm completely unsure how to go about making that happen.

**Update:**

Code used to update `people`

```
  {{#autoForm collection="people" id=formId type="update" class="update" autocomplete="off" doc=getDocument autosave=true template="quickform"}}
  {{> afQuickField name='note' template="quickform" }}
  {{/autoForm}}
```

`formId` returns a randomish ID string and `getDocument` passes in the correct collection.

`Schemas.notes._schemaKeys` does not list the `at` and `user_id` fields... but `Schemas.people._schemaKeys` does.

People schema shows: [..., "updates.$.at", "updates.$.user_id", ...]

Notes schema shows: ["note", "updates", "updates.$"]

How bizarre.

Comment: Can you please include the code that updates the `people` document?

Comment: @BrianShamblen I added it, but it's fairly straightforward autoform code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Meteor uses standard JavaScript syntax and therefore has the same restrictions, for example as you already realized order of code is important.

Let's have a look.

```
Schemas.notes = new SimpleSchema({
  updates: {
    type: [Schemas.updates]
  }
}
```

There are no nested functions in this code, therefore every code of line will be executed, before Meteor continues with the next Schema definition. `Schema.updates` will be dereferenced immediately, although it isn't set yet. `type` will be an array containing `null` and that finally makes SimpleSchema assume that no fields are allowed at all.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the order in which the schemas are declared. Which I suppose makes sense? I was declaring "notes" before "updates", and "people" last. Putting "updates" first fixed the issue completely.

I'm going to report this as a possible bug to the collection repo.